# Does a verb version of "Beispiel" exist?

Tags: word-usage, single-word-request

I wonder if a verb version of "Beispiel" exists. For example, can I say: "beispielen"?

"Er arbeitet hart. Acht, zehn, zwölf Stunden am Tag!"

For this sentence I would like to ask like the following question:

> Welches Stilmittel ist im obigen Satz beispielt worden?(1)
>
> Welches Beispiel des Stilmittels ist im obigen Satz gemacht worden?(2)

Which type of my questions is better or both are nonsense?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/exemplifizieren, but don't use it

Comment: Wenn, dann müsste es nach meinem Sprachgefühl im ersten Fall "bebeispielt" heißen (benutzt worden, beispielhaft benutzt worden). Der zweite müsste wohl "Welches Beispiel eines Stilmittels..." lauten, aber ich weiß gar nicht, was gefragt wird. :) Welches Stilmittel denn?

Comment: @userunknown it is Klimax

Comment: Just try and ask Google.de for "bebeispielen" - And it will come back with a claim this exists. And I guess the claim is wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use any of those sentences - both sound strange, and no native speaker would use them. "*Ein Beispiel machen*" is at least colloquial - i wouldn't expect it in a book. Instead, use a different verb that fits better. For example:

> - [einen Sachverhalt] veranschaulichen
> - [ein bestimmtes Verhalten] demonstrieren, vorführen
> - [ein bestimmtes Stilmittel] [beispielhaft / beispielhalber] verwenden, einsetzen, nutzen, wählen

As in my last example, you may additionally use an adjective ("*beispielhaft*") or adverb ("*beispielhalber*") that [stems from "*Beispiel*".](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/beispiel:N:N)

EDIT:

In a complete sentence, i would write:

> *Welches Stilmittel wird in diesem Satz verwendet* (or: *genutzt* / *benutzt* / *eingesetzt*)*?*

Explanation: You can't use "*ist verwendet*", unless you continue "*... worden*". Also, i've replaced "*obiger*" by "*diesem*", assuming that the reference is clear enough, and "*obiger*" sounds quite "officialese".

Comment: I would never say "ein Beispiel machen", but "ein Beispiel geben".

Comment: You did not provide an example sentence, I'll try after all: Welches Stilfigur is im obigen Satz beispielhaft eingesetzt?

Comment: @Dragut: i'm not very happy with your example sentence - i've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Could I also use "benutzen" instead "nutzen", I've learnt that "nutzen" means "to make use of something, to get benefit from something".

Comment: Yes - "_... wird in diesem Satz benutzt_" would be possible, too.

Answer (score 6):

I think explicitly asking for what something is an example does not make much sense. In your context you could say something like:

- Wofür ist der obige Satz ein Beispiel?
- Für welches Stilmittel ist obiger Satz ein Beispiel?

More natural are the questions along the line of tohuwawohu's answer. I would ask (for example in a test or quiz):

- Welches Stilmittel wird in diesem Satz verwendet?

Answer (score 2):

There is no verb for the noun "Beispiel", but you could use a combination of the Adjektiv ("beispielhaft") and a verb, like:

> Welches Stilmittel ist im obigen Satz **beispielhaft verwendet worden**?(1)

Comment: thanks but what is difference between "Welches Stilmittel ist im obigen Satz beispielhaft verwendet" and "Welches Stilmittel ist im obigen Satz beispielhaft verwendet worden"?

Comment: One can't say it makes any difference. Well it's another tense, but it actually means the same. I used past, because one has already read the example (sentence). You can also use present, because you are currently progressing on this sentence :) It's up to what you prefer

Comment: @Dragut: I think “Welches Stilmittel ist im obigen Satz beispielhaft verwendet” is not correct. The construction used here is the “Passiv” form “verwendet werden” (Infinitiv) from which you can derive different tenses: “wird verwendet” (Präsens), “wurde verwendet” (Präteritum), “ist verwendet worden” (Perfekt). In your first sentence the Hilfsverb “werden“ which is required for the Passiv is missing.

Comment: @CorneliusSicker I understand but can't it be used as case passive(Zustandpassiv),because the whole process is completed already i.e. "is done", why we can't write "Welches Stilmittel ist im obigen Satz beispielhaft verwendet". I gave the examples and it is done any more, it is written, I've finished.